# Sending private messages using Flask-SocketIO

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am making a simple social media website for my uni using Flask and now I reached to the point when I create the real-time chat engine. I chose SocketIO for this task. I'm trying to to send a messages to only a specific user. The users have unique names on the site so I use the names as their ids and to set the room to the desired username to whom we want to send. But When I send the message, I receive it on my side but the other user doesn't receive anything. I want the receiver to receive the message in real-time. Actually, I don't know if this's the right approach to do it and the fact that I have a little experience with Javascript.

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/messages')
def messages():
    if 'user_id' in session:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        name = session['name'] //logged-in username
        user_search =request.form.get('user_search') //the desired user who we want to send a message

        room = user_search //now, the room is set to that user
        return render_template('messages.html', name=name, room=room)

    else:
        return redirect('/')


@socketio.on('send_message')
def handle_send_message_event(data):
    app.logger.info("{} has sent message to the room {}: {}".format(data['name'],
                                                                    data['room'],
                                                                    data['message']))
    socketio.emit('receive_message', data, room=data['room'])
```

**app.js**

```
<script>

        const socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000");

        socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.emit('join_room', {
            name: "{{ name }}",
            room: "{{ room }}"
            })

        let message_input = document.getElementById('message_input');

        document.getElementById('message_input_form').onsubmit = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let message = message_input.value.trim();
            if (message.length) {
                    socket.emit('send_message', {
                    name: "{{ name }}",
                    room: "{{ room }}",
                    message: message
                })
            }
            message_input.value = '';
            message_input.focus();
        }
    });

        socket.on('receive_message', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        const newNode = document.createElement('div');
        newNode.innerHTML = `<b>${data.name}:&nbsp;</b> ${data.message}`;
        document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(newNode);
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: What is `{{ room }}`? That should be the room of the other person, but if I understand your code correctly it is really the room of the user sending the message. How does this JS code know the room of the other user?

Comment: @Miguel Yes, you're correct. It's the room of the user sending the message. This's my problem actually. I am not be able to figure out how to get the room of the other user and where to do it. I was thinking about it but I couldn't figure out. Can you please suggest me anything can be useful to solve my problem?

Comment: But this is an application logic problem, not an issue with Python, JavaScript or the libraries that you are using. How your application knows what user to send a message to is actually a decision that you need to make as part of designing your application, right? How could I know what your plans for this application are?